# Implications of using GLSurfaceView on power consumption and battery life

Tags: android, battery

My app is using GLSurfaceView for displaying images (and fast transformation). I've noticed that even when I merely initialize the surface, fill it with solid color and don't call any further OpenGL functions, after some time of activity staying in foreground the tablet starts getting hot. CPU consumption is almost 0%, so I assume it's GPU. Am I right? And if so, is there any way to throttle GPU? The operations I'm using OpenGL for are not at all performance-demanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the render mode to RENDERMODE_ONDEMAND? See docs here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setRenderMode(int)

Comment: No, I didn't notice this method. However, now that I've called `setRenderMode(RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY)` after `setRenderer` I don't see any improvement in heat generation. But I can confirm that `GLSurfaceView.onDrawFrame` has been called excessively, but no more.